# Magento 2 - trigger order email and invoice on status change

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

In a custom Magento 2 module, I have some code that successfully creates an order from a quote and sets the status to "pending".

After payment, I would like to programmatically validate the order, generate the invoice and send the confirmation email to the client.

The code that sets the status to complete:

```
// Update the status
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
$order->setStatus('complete');
$order->save();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't generate an invoice and send the final email. How are we supposed to perform these action programmatically from an existing/pending order?

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento, the Order will automatically change the status to `completed` when it has Invoice and Shippment.

We can create invoice programmatically with `\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService::prepareInvoice();`

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save.php::save()`

```
$invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $invoiceItems);

$invoice->register();
```

And then, try to send email by using `Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceManagementInterface::notify()`

For the shippment, you can google to find the way to create the shipment.