# Send an email upon order status change

Tags: event-observer, email, magento2.3

I'm trying to find a way to programtically send out an email, that doesn't depend on some front-end or admin behavior. Ideally, this email would be sent when the order status is changed to 'processing'. From what I gather, there isn't an event I can use for this, nor can an email be sent using the API. Does anyone know of a way to do this, or some kind of work-around that will result in basically this type of behavior? I found this event: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. I'm not sure how it works. It seems to fire off when the order success page is loaded, which wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - trigger order email and invoice on status change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168012/magento-2-trigger-order-email-and-invoice-on-status-change)

Comment: I think I'll have the same problem with this method. Sending out an email isn't the problem. It's triggering the email to send contingent upon some change to the order (status). I'm looking for a way to fire off some code when there is a change to an order that has already been placed.